# A question related to time and motion

Tags: kinematics, time

I have a theory, I think that we cannot travel at speeds faster than light because, as we know,when you travel at speeds near light time passes slowly and that if we go further than light time may pause perhaps and that if time pauses its impossible to have motion because in 0 seconds (  I mean no time has passed) you cannot travel any distance.

I have also another theory, I think that if we go a little high than light speed except pausing time may reverse, and if time reverses an object will never exists in space but continuously go back in time and reach big bang. The object will never exist in space but actually in a TIME dimension ( I know dimension word is wrong but I couldn't think of a word except this).

Can anyone one of these 'theories' be true, even very tiny bit true? Please point out my mistakes. I am just a kid though of 9th grade. But, I really wonder could these be true or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interesting idea, I had a few thoughts too when I was in the 9th grade, but now you have to understand that it's true that when you travel close to the speed of light **your surroundings** seem to move very slowly but why you can't travel at the speed of light is not because time pauses. Time pauses for light waves too but they *do* exist.

The reason you can't reach the speed of light is because you  have **mass** when at rest. Thus, as you approach the speed of light you again mass from your increase in kinetic energy. So with more mass you need more and more energy to travel faster. So to actually reach the speed of light you'll need an infinite amount of energy. **That is** why particles with mass can't reach light speed.

Also, due to this a faster than light, scenario is theoretically impossible in a fixed space.

Answer (score 0):

[PBS Spacetime's YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/) has several videos related to your theories.  There are specific methods physicists use to examine Light and Time.  One of them is the [Penrose diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_diagram):

[image: Example Penrose diagram]

Here are some of the videos where they talk about Time, Black Holes, and Superluminal Travel... all of which examine how the geometry of spacetime is utilized to draw conclusions on fringe topics:

[Superluminal Time Travel + Time Warp Challenge Answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUMGc8hEkpc)

[image: Superluminal Time Travel + Time Warp Challenge Answer]

[How Time Becomes Space Inside a Black Hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KePNhUJ2reI)

[image: How Time Becomes Space Inside a Black Hole]

[The Geometry of Causality](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YFrISfN7jo)

[image: The Geometry of Causality]

[What Happens at the Event Horizon?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mht-1c4wc0Q)

[image: What Happens at the Event Horizon?]

Answer (score 0):

It is a common misconception to believe that if you move close to the speed of light you cannot move because time is slow. You do not experience anything different, other than how the rest of the universe looks to you. Everything will looks shorter and running very slow in time. But you will see the objects past you at high speed. Also, objects that move along you at the same speed will be normally experienced.